# Conversion of '2013-05-22 02:00pm' to '2013-05-22 14:00' in R

Tags: r, strptime

I want to convert the following format into a standard date format in R:

```
2013-05-22 02:00pm
```

to

```
2013-05-22 14:00
```

I've tried using strptime, but it outputs `2013-05-22 02:00 MST`, which would mean 2AM. How do I fix this?

Comment: Please show the code you tried.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich strptime(samp, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%M')

Comment: `"%h"` is the "Abbreviated month name in the current locale." Please read the documentation more carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`?strptime` says you must use `"%I"` (not `"%H"`) with `"%p"`.

```
> strptime('2013-05-22 02:00pm', tz="UTC", format="%Y-%m-%d %I:%M%p")
[1] "2013-05-22 14:00:00 UTC"
```